# Involk javascript function in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to call a simple javascript method in my Java code.  Basically I want to show a textbox on my jsp page that is displayed when you click on a button.  After I hit submit the textbox is gone, I want to keep the textbox on display.

Here is my front end code:

```
<input name="mytext" type="text" id="text" style="display:none;"/>
```

Here is my Java code where I am trying to force the textbox to stay displayed after submit:

```
if(isClean==true && hasError==false)
{
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();  
                    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");  
                                           //using the text id in my jsp page
String myscript = "function Show() {document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'; }";  
 // evaluate script  
engine.eval(script);  


 Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;  

inv.invokeFunction("Show" ); 
            }
        }
```

I have a function in my Javascript that functions very well off the same function, however, when I call it from Java, it just does not seem to want to work.

Any suggestions would be great and thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the Java code in an applet, standalone, or on the webserver?

Comment: Calling javascript from java...I have 3 words for you...no no no!

Comment: You appear to have a very deep misunderstanding of how and where JSPs execute. Suffice to say that anything that you do with the *server-side* `ScriptEngine` has no relationship to what happens on the browser.

Comment: The words client and server spring to mind...

Comment: Before you continue developing web applications; learn what runs on the server and what runs on the client browser.  Along with "what", "when" will matter as well.  The server side stuff (java) runs before the page is visible in the browser; the browser side stuff (javascript) runs after th epage is loaded into the browser.

Comment: No, its not an applet, its on a web server.